# Can CLGeocoder work worldwide, beyond US?

Tags: ios, clgeocoder

I'm not seeing anything explicitly mentioned in the documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/Reference/Reference.html

Essentially what I want to know is whether this can also work in Europe.

Gratzi

Comment: Ya CLGeocoder will work for limited countries.Use google API for others like http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=46.0000,7.0000&sensor=true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

...it is mentioned in the documentation, I think you've just overlooked it!

[List of supported countries for CLGeocoder](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2289/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011305)